# jQuery animation of large image moving choppy

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://henrybuiltfurniture.com/new/furniture.php?p=wave-stool

I have a series of large images that I need to transition between smoothly (not necessarily with jquery - maybe I could use css3 somehow?) and I can't seem to do so with jQuery.

Here's the code that moves the document, effectively moving the image:

```
$('body').animate({scrollLeft: $("#limiter"+(viewing+1)).css("left")}, image_change_speed, 'easeOutCirc', function() {
    //irrelevant code here
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this to your CSS style sheet:

```
.limiter * {
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Basically, we're adding hardware acceleration and then smoothing effect with transition (you can adjust it at will, of course)

Comment: You should probably also use vendor-prefixed versions of the transition property too.

Comment: all modern browsers support transition, but just in case for old browsers he can add -webkit-transition (everything else works fine so non needed at all)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use straight up jQuery for more demanding animations, as you mentioned. I would scrap jQuery alltogether or get a css3 animation plugin for it. Using vanilla javascript, this is a really simplified example of how to animate the images:

Say you have two images:

```
<img src="http://henrybuiltfurniture.com/new/images/6_5.jpg" class='bigimg img-1'>
<img src="http://henrybuiltfurniture.com/new/images/6_4.jpg" class='bigimg img-2'>
```

And some styles to put them at the right place:

```
.bigimg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    transition: transform 2s;
}

.img-1 {
    left: 0;
}
.img-2 {
    left: 1920px;
}
```

Then you could easily animate by just changing the bigimg's transform:

```
var bigImages = document.querySelectorAll('.bigimg');

for(var i = 0; i < bigImages.length; i++) {
    var image = bigImages[i];
    image.style.transform = 'translateX(-1920px)';
}
```

Example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgd8srwz/)

Paul irish has a [great article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) going through why it is better to animate `transform` rather than `position: absolute` with `left` and `top` attributes if you would like some further reading.

Comment: Of course this would need some vendor prefixes (and maybe a jQuery fallback) for maximized browser support, but it works out of the box in chrome at least

Comment: If you would like to continue doing this in a jQuery-way I recommend checking out http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ wich can animate using css3 using $(..).transition() just like $(..).animate()